# outiler and residual plot

Tags: outliers

I have a general question. If you have Duration vs Cost graph and you can see some outliers. (let cost be the target variable and duration is a variable) Then, you may need to omit these outliers.

But, if you see a residual plot, the residual does not look bad because your actual points and expected points (i.e. predictions) are both bad. Then, is it your choice to remove or keep the outliers?